# How to find remainder of this expression using modular arithmetic?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the remainder of $2016^{{{201}^{20}}^2}$ divided by 19.

It's a bit tricky, I know that remainder of 2016 divided by 19 is 2, but I don't know where to go from there, from $2^{{{201}^{20}}^2}$.

Any ideas or tricks to use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As $2016\equiv2\pmod{19},$

$2016^n\equiv2^n\pmod{19}$  for any integer $n\ge0$

Now as $3|201,3^2|201^2$ and $2^9\equiv-1\pmod{19}$

Also, ${{201}^{20}}^2$ as odd, it  can be written as $9(2m+1)$ where $m$ is a positive integer

Finally, $2^{9(2m+1)}=(2^9)^{2m+1}\equiv(-1)^{2m+1}\pmod{19}=?$